# How to get the `public` dir from Symfony4 Controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to get `public` dir from the function in Controller Class SYmfony4

I have tried three types but in vain.

`print $this->get('kernel')->getProjectDir();`

`print $container->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');`

`print $this->appKernel->getProjectDir();`

The first one shows this error message like this,
I guess there is some hints.....

```
Service "kernel" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\MemberController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Unless you need extra laziness, try using dependency injection instead. Otherwise, you need to declare it using "MemberController::getSubscribedServices()".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You was close. Try [`AbstractController::getParameter()`](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/06964949acd0fd8099f7af3fffa44467e2499178/Controller/AbstractController.php#L78) inside your controller method:

```
$this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir') . '/public';
```

**FYI** this actually is not a good practice and raise testing complexity.
Better solution is using dependency injection.